# Не могу доработать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.

SQL запрос:

```
SELECT oref 
     ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ref=oref)
     ,COUNT(DISTINCT(login)) AS bia 
FROM operations 
WHERE sum>0 AND oref!='' 
GROUP BY oref 
ORDER BY bia DESC LIMIT 10
```

Собственно, необходимо, чтобы SQL запрос считал в еще одном столбце такой запрос SELECT sum(sum)  FROM `operations` WHERE `oref` = 'логин'

Comment: Тут не столбец надо добавлять, а весь запрос переписывать. Так что лучше описывайте задачу, а не свою попытку её решать.

Comment: Ну вот прямо так и добавьте, как тот подзапрос, что уже есть. хотя это будет явно не оптимальным, но рабочим. А если сделать оптимально, то уточните задачу, бывают ли в таблице отрицательные sum т.е. можно ли для конкретного логина посчитать как в остальном запросе только строки sum>0

Comment: Ну задача такова: получить всю сумму приведенных клиентом рефералов. А в запросе показывается только количество рефералов + сколько активных. А необходимо показать еще сумму, сумма показывается вот таким запросом SELECT sum(sum) FROM operations WHERE oref = 'логин'

Comment: Сможет кто-то помочь?